# On the upper bound for the real part of the logarithmic derivative of a polynomial

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n, a_n\neq 0$ with $\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|=1.$ May  it be true that  for all $z$ on $|z|=1,$ for which $P(z)\neq 0,$
$$\Re{\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)}}\leq n-\frac{1+|a_0|-|a_n|}{1+|a_0|+|a_n|}?$$ or else any counter example?

Comment: No. If this were true for all polynomials with $P(z)\neq 0$, then the same would be true for all polynomials, by continuity. But it is evidently wrong for some polynomials with $P(z)=0$, for example for $P(z)=z-1$, and $z=1$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko $z-1$ does not satisfy the last assumption in the first line of the post, does it?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I did. The real part is exactly at $1/2$ (the circle goes exactly to the critical line).

Comment: @fedja That is right.

Comment: @fedja,Any polynomial P(z) having all its zeros outside $|z|<1$ satisfies $\Re(zP'(z)/P(z))\leq n/2$ for all z on $|z|=1$ for which $P(z)\neq 0.$

Comment: Polynomial $P(z)=(2/3)z-1/3$ satisfies all conditions. Your inequality is violated for $z=1$.